# sum function in select query working fine on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing addition of time from database through query using sqlite database.but sum function in select query is working fine on emulator not on device.it will give me null value on device

```
public class MonthlyStatistics extends Fragment {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> date,time,distance;

    public MonthlyStatistics(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monthly_statistics, container, false);
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthlystatistics);

        date = new ArrayList<String>();
        time = new ArrayList<String>();
        distance = new ArrayList<String>();
        String year = getDate();
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            Cursor c = null;
            String SqlQuery = "SELECT time(sum(strftime('%s',time)),'unixepoch') AS time_total,sum(distance) AS total_km,date AS month FROM walkingdetail where date like '"+year+"-0"+i+"-%%'";

            if (i < 10) {

                c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time_total")) != null
                            && c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("total_km")) != null) {

                        date.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("month")));
                        time.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time_total")));
                        distance.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("total_km")));
                    }
                }
                c.close();
            } else {
                c = database
                        .rawQuery(query, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time_total")) != null
                            && c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("total_km")) != null) {

                        date.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("month")));
                        time.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time_total")));
                        distance.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("total_km")));
                    }

                }
                c.close();
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: both device and emulator have same time zone , language ? and can u pls check in tht particular table "walkingdetail" data count(number of rows) are you getting ?

Comment: yes.i have checked all the thing.i get data without sum function.